# Switch fallthrough all cases below the selected case in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an industrial app using flutter. The app involves lot of input from user be it TextFormField or `DropDownSearchField`.

If user changes/modifies the data/value of any field that is above current field all the data of below field must be cleared.

e.g. : If user has set 10 of 12 field numbered (1 to 12), then user decides to change Field 3 then all field below Field 3 must be cleared (reset).

I was looking into Switch fallthrough but dart seems to give me error `The 'case' should not complete normally. Try adding 'break', or 'return', etc.`

I really want to avoid code duplication where by I write clear code in each case. Using if statement is complicating logic. I looked into [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641818/6319901) but I wish to avoid label and continue statement (as this look like goto statement from other languages).

What are my options here?

Code :

```
void clearDataAfterStepChange({required int step}) {
    switch (step) {
      //Clear All Steps Below 1 -> Product Code
      case 1:
        _productCodeController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 2 -> Batch Number
      case 2:
        _batchNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 3 -> Area
      case 3:
        _areaController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 4 -> Room Name
      case 4:
        _roomNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 5 -> Stage
      case 5:
        _stageController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 6 -> Product Type
      case 6:
        _productTypeController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 7 -> Product Name
      case 7:
        _productNameController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 8 -> Product Version Number
      case 8:
        _productVersionNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 9 -> Version Number
      case 9:
        _versionNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 10 -> BMR Number
      case 10:
        _bmrNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 11 -> BMR Version Number
      case 11:
        _bmrVersionNumberController.clear();
      //Clear All Steps Below 12 -> Process Order Number
      case 12:
        _processOrderNumberController.clear();
      // Do Nothing
      default:
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I prefer using `if` conditional state in this case

Answer (score 0):

Forget `switch` statement, it won't solve this problem.
So try this way :

```
 void clearDataAfterStepChange({required int step}) {
     Map<int, TextEditingController> textControllerMap = {
    11: _processOrderNumberController,
    10: _bmrVersionNumberController,
    9: _bmrNumberController,
    8: _versionNumberController,
    7: _productVersionNumberController,
    6: _productNameController,
    5: _productTypeController,
    4: _stageController,
    3: _roomNumberController,
    2: _areaController,
    1: _batchNumberController,
  };

  for (int i = 1; i <= textControllerMap.length; i++) {
    if (step <= i) {
      textControllerMap[i].clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will cause code duplication and lot of maintenance issue.

Comment: Right, check this new approach. I have edited my previous answer. @DarkSorrow

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using `continue LABEL`.  That's what it's there for. (There's also nothing inherently wrong with using `goto` in C either, and in some common situations it's *good* form, but I digress.)

However, in your specific case where each step invokes a single zero-argument function<sup>1</sup>, you could create a `List` of callbacks of each of the steps, and then just iterate over them and invoke them:

```dart
void clearDataAfterStepChange({required int step}) {
  var steps = <void Function(void)>[
    _productCodeController.clear,
    _batchNumberController.clear,
    _areaController.clear,
    _roomNumberController.clear,
    _stageController.clear,
    _productTypeController.clear,
    _productNameController.clear,
    _productVersionNumberController.clear,
    _versionNumberController.clear,
    _bmrNumberController.clear,
    _bmrVersionNumberController.clear,
    _processOrderNumberController.clear,
  ];
  
  for (var i = step - 1; i >= 0 && i < steps.length; i += 1) {
    steps[i]();
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You could still do it even if each step were more complex too, but it would be uglier.